# conditional regexp in python

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a simple requirement to split lines in a file. The file is csv format and the dilimitter is ','. Not even a regexp is needed, a simple split(',') will do for most cases.

However, I have some lines go like,

```
Sale,8/18/2017,"99 RANCH #1601 001658500 - EDISON, NJ",-225.07,Supplie
```

In which case I need the code to detect the " first, ignore the comma in it and treat the part between " as a whole component.

How do we go about to deal with this with regexp? I am using Python3.

Comment: Can't you just read the csv in with the csv module? I think commas withing quotes aren't counted as delimiters

Comment: Why not use the `csv` module?  It already handles these (and many other) cases correctly.